# Framebuffer Documentation

Tags: linux, framebuffer

Is there any documentation on how to write software that uses the framebuffer device in Linux?  I've seen a couple simple examples that basically say: "open it, mmap it, write pixels to mapped area."  But no comprehensive documentation on how to use the different IOCTLS for it anything.  I've seen references to "panning" and other capabilities but "googling it" gives way too many hits of useless information.

Edit:
Is the only documentation from a programming standpoint, not a "User's howto configure your system to use the fb," documentation the code?

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look at fbi's source code, an image viewer which uses the linux framebuffer. You can get it here : http://linux.bytesex.org/fbida/

Answer (score 3):

-- It appears there might not be too many options possible to programming with the fb from user space on a desktop beyond what you mentioned. This might be one reason why some of the docs are so old. Look at this howto for *device driver writers* and which is referenced from some official linux docs: www.linux-fbdev.org [slash] HOWTO [slash] index.html . It does not reference too many interfaces.. although looking at the linux source tree does offer larger code examples.

-- opentom.org [slash] Hardware_Framebuffer is not for a desktop environment. It reinforces the main methodology, but it does seem to avoid explaining all the ingredients necessary to doing the "fast" double buffer switching it mentions. Another one for a different device and which leaves some key buffering details out is wiki.gp2x.org [slash] wiki [slash] Writing_to_the_framebuffer_device , although it does at least suggest you might be able use fb1 and fb0 to engage double buffering (on this device.. though for desktop, fb1 may not be possible or it may access different hardware), that using volatile keyword might be appropriate, and that we should pay attention to the vsync.

-- asm.sourceforge.net [slash] articles [slash] fb.html assembly language routines that also appear (?) to just do the basics of querying, opening, setting a few basics, mmap, drawing pixel values to storage, and copying over to the fb memory (making sure to use a short stosb loop, I suppose, rather than some longer approach).

-- Beware of 16 bpp comments when googling Linux frame buffer: I used fbgrab and fb2png during an X session to no avail. These each rendered an image that suggested a snapshot of my desktop screen as if the picture of the desktop had been taken using a very bad camera, underwater, and then overexposed in a dark room. The image was completely broken in color, size, and missing much detail (dotted all over with pixel colors that didn't belong). It seems that /proc /sys on the computer I used (new kernel with at most minor modifications.. from a PCLOS derivative) claim that fb0 uses 16 bpp, and most things I googled stated something along those lines, but experiments lead me to a very different conclusion. Besides the results of these two failures from standard frame buffer grab utilities (for the versions held by this distro) that may have assumed 16 bits, I had a different successful test result treating frame buffer pixel data as 32 bits. I created a file from data pulled in via cat /dev/fb0. The file's size ended up being 1920000. I then wrote a small C program to try and manipulate that data (under the assumption it was pixel data in some encoding or other). I nailed it eventually, and the pixel format matched exactly what I had gotten from X when queried (TrueColor RGB 8 bits, no alpha but padded to 32 bits). Notice another clue: my screen resolution of 800x600 times 4 bytes gives 1920000 exactly. The 16 bit approaches I tried initially all produced a similar broken image to fbgrap, so it's not like if I may not have been looking at the right data. [Let me know if you want the code I used to test the data. Basically I just read in the entire fb0 dump and then spit it back out to file, after adding a header "P6\n800 600\n255\n" that creates the suitable ppm file, and while looping over all the pixels manipulating their order or expanding them,.. with the end successful result for me being to drop every 4th byte and switch the first and third in every 4 byte unit. In short, I turned the apparent BGRA fb0 dump into a ppm RGB file. ppm can be viewed with many pic viewers on Linux.]

-- You may want to reconsider the reasons for wanting to program using fb0 (this might also account for why few examples exist). You may not achieve any worthwhile performance gains over X (this was my, if limited, experience) while giving up benefits of using X. This reason might also account for why few code examples exist.

-- Note that DirectFB is not fb. DirectFB has of late gotten more love than the older fb, as it is more focused on the sexier 3d hw accel. If you want to render to a desktop screen as fast as possible without leveraging 3d hardware accel (or even 2d hw accel), then fb might be fine but won't give you anything much that X doesn't give you. X apparently uses fb, and the overhead is likely negligible compared to other costs your program will likely have (don't call X in any tight loop, but instead at the end once you have set up all the pixels for the frame). On the other hand, it can be neat to play around with fb as covered in this comment: [Paint Pixels to Screen via Linux FrameBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996777/paint-pixels-to-screen-via-linux-framebuffer/5927457#5927457)

Answer (score 3):

Check for [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) sources.

Under the */libvo* directory there are a lot of Video Output plugins used by Mplayer to display multimedia. There you can find the *fbdev* (vo_fbdev* sources) plugin which uses the Linux frame buffer.

There are a lot of ioctl calls, with the following codes:

- FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO
- FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO
- FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO
- FBIOGETCMAP
- FBIOPUTCMAP
- FBIOPAN_DISPLAY

It's not like a good documentation, but this is surely a good application implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Look at source code of any of: fbxat,fbida, fbterm, fbtv, directFB library, libxineliboutput-fbe, ppmtofb, xserver-fbdev all are debian packages apps. Just apt-get source from debian libraries. there are many others...

**hint**: search for framebuffer in package description using your favorite package manager.

ok, even if reading the code is sometimes called "*Guru documentation*" it can be a bit too much to actually do it.

Comment: For something like this where everybody and there brother is writing there own version the problem is the behaviour from one to the next may not be the same if there is no documentation to guide developers through implementing the API.  I was looking at the source for the PS3 Linux implementation, you can see there are features which appear to be commonly implemented which they ignored.

Comment: @NoMoreZealots: Yes, a true documentation with best practice guidelines would be a very good thing. I really don't know one (so I upvoted your question), my answer was a kind of joke ;-) You may have to write that one...

Answer (score 0):

The source to any splash screen (i.e. during booting) should give you a good start.

Comment: That's a bit general, could ya give me a more specific direction to look?