# Video stream output via USB/TRRS port using OPENCV

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry and I process video from a camera connected via usb on it, I need to display in real time only the processed video directly through the usb/trrs port (not the entire desktop with an opencv window, but the video itself).
In the end, I just need to connect another board and it received a raspberry output at its input as if it were just a camera.

P.S. C++/python implementation doesn't matter.

P.P.S. Wireless transmission is not suitable, it is necessary that the raspberry simulate the output of the usb/ trrs like real camera

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: OpenCV is for computer vision, not for making GUIs or video output. ask this on a raspberry-pi-specific forum. you seem to ask for specific hardware capabilities.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank for advice, I will ask it on a rpi forum)

Answer (score 1):

Some steps:

1. Connect the raspberry to the display
2. ctrl + alt + f1
3. `sudo service lightdm stop`
4. `ls /dev/fb*` (should be our screen's framebuffer type fb0)

and then work with opencv like this

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
frame32 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
fbframe = cv2.resize(frame32, (1920,1080))
with open('/dev/fb0', 'rb+') as buf:
buf.write(fbframe)
```

[thread that helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718147/developing-for-the-hdmi-port-on-linux)