# How to access the kernel’s stdout like an API?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I would like to have instant access to the information of all the pixels that are being displayed on the pc’s monitor. I want this so I can post evaluate and use the information of all the colors on the display. Is there any way to get this information in linux?

Comment: [This](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Color_of_a_screen_pixel#C) might be useful - it uses the X window manager's functionality instead of the linux kernel. Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866742/how-to-get-rgb-pixel-values-from-linux-framebuffer) though, it looks like this is the best option.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the pixels" and what Linux are you using ? Open a `Terminal` and then type `cat /var/log/messages` o